# Jqgrid with jsonreader the userdata response in firebug is undefined

Tags: jqgrid, coldfusion, user-data, jsonreader

I am trying to access userdata I have sent from the server (using coldfusion) to filter the display of edit or add icons depending on users's role. Example of userdata value is "all" or "add" or "edit" or "view".

```
From firebug an example of userdata looks like
,"USERDATA":"all"
```

The jsonreader looks like this

```
jsonReader: {
    root: "ROWS", //our data
                page: "PAGE", //current page
                total: "TOTAL", //total pages
                records:"RECORDS", //total records
    userdata: "USERDATA", 
                cell: "", //Not Used
    ar_bill_key: "0",//Will default to first column
    id:"10" 
      },
```

I am trying to find the userdata so I can figure out how to use it. The code below returns undefined in firebug. I'm new to this so it's not set up correctly. Any advice would be appreciated. I have looked at and tried many examples but it's not working yet

```
loadComplete:jQuery("#List").getGridParam("userdata")

     alert("userdata")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors. The first one is: the name of parameter is `'userData'` and not `'userdata'`. So to get the value send from the server you should use

```
var myData = $("#List").jqGrid('getGridParam', "userData");
```

The next error: the `loadComplete` is a callback *function* so the code

```
loadComplete:jQuery("#List").getGridParam("userdata")
```

is wrong.

The last error is: the value of `userdata` which will be sent from the server have to be **object**. So you should place something like

```
"USERDATA":{"status":"all"}
```

instead or

```
"USERDATA":{"status":"all"}
```

If you use

```
jsonReader: {
    ... 
    userdata: "USERDATA",
    ...
}
```

then you can display the value from `loadComplete` like the following:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var myData = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', "userData");
    alert(myData.status);
}
```